# How do I convert list of three element dictionary (First element: term,Second Element: position,Third : Value) into list of two element dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, logic

I have the below list with me (This list is already truncated):

```
[
  [['write', 1, 1], ['bob', 1, 1], ['econom', 1, 1], ['hate', 1, 1], ['articl', 1, 1], ['mcgwier', 1, 1], ['howev', 1, 1], ['terror', 1, 1]],
  [['polit', 2, 1], ['approach', 2, 1], ['correct', 2, 1], ['hate', 2, 1], ['effect', 2, 1], ['polici', 2, 1], ['stop', 2, 1], ['wors', 2, 1]], 
  [['support', 3, 1], ['organiz', 3, 1], ['directli', 3, 1], ['donat', 3, 1], ['right', 3, 1], ['indirectli', 3, 1], ['gay', 3, 1], ['issu', 3, 1]], 
  [['boycott', 4, 1], ['somebodi', 4, 1], ['appar', 4, 1], ['contradict', 4, 1], ['fund', 4, 1], ['end', 4, 1], ['reconcil', 4, 1], ['scout', 4, 1]], 
  [['road', 5, 1], ['saw', 5, 1], ['river', 5, 1], ['strom', 5, 1], ['research', 5, 1], ['mill', 5, 1], ['rob', 5, 1], ['ibm', 5, 1]],
  [['height', 6, 1], ['yorktown', 6, 1], ['p', 6, 1], ['box', 6, 1], ['ny', 6, 1]]
]
```

The first element in list **['write', 1, 1]** is **'write'** is the term second **'1'** is position and third is value of that term at that position **'1'**

I have another list of unique terms :

```
[(1093, 'scout', 1), (661, 'issu', 1), (379, 'econom', 1), (1154, 'somebodi', 1), (395, 'end', 1), (57, 'appar', 1), (921, 'polici', 1), (247, 'contradict', 1), (1066, 'rob', 1), (62, 'approach', 1), (259, 'correct', 1), (1061, 'right', 1), (1377, 'write', 1), (1023, 'reconcil', 1), (1232, 'terror', 1), (1208, 'support', 1), (334, 'directli', 1), (75, 'articl', 1), (381, 'effect', 1), (624, 'indirectli', 1), (140, 'bob', 1), (502, 'fund', 1), (578, 'howev', 1), (1084, 'saw', 1), (1064, 'river', 1), (1383, 'yorktown', 1), (554, 'hate', 2), (864, 'organiz', 1), (839, 'ny', 1), (356, 'donat', 1), (560, 'height', 1), (874, 'p', 1), (1192, 'stop', 1), (1195, 'strom', 1), (145, 'boycott', 1), (1051, 'research', 1), (1372, 'wors', 1), (144, 'box', 1), (922, 'polit', 1), (1065, 'road', 1), (781, 'mill', 1), (586, 'ibm', 1), (513, 'gay', 1), (757, 'mcgwier', 1)]
```

The second list is having unique terms with their ID and value at end **(1093, 'scout', 1)** ; here **1093** is ID, **'scout'** is unique term and **1** is value.

This second list is for help.

I want an output list like this, which will contain all the unique terms and ID of second list and value from first list at it's specified position in first list:

```
[[1377,'write',[1,0,0,0,0,0]],[554, 'hate',[1,1,0,0,0,0]], ......]
```

Where in **[1377,'write',[1,0,0,0,0,0]]**, **'1377'** is ID from second list, **'write'** is term from second list and **[1,0,0,0,0,0]** are the value from first list to the corresponding position.

In **'write'** you can see in first positional list **'['write', 1, 1]'** is indicating that 'write' have a value of '1' at first position and 'write' does not apper any where else, so output of 'write' is **[1,0,0,0,0,0]** in final output string **[1377,'write',[1,0,0,0,0,0]]**.

Same in 'hate' you can see in first positional list **'['hate', 1, 1]'** is indicating that 'hate' have a value of '1' at '1'st position and in second positional list **'['hate', 2, 1]'** is indicating that 'hate' have a value of '1' at '2'nd position and 'hate' does not apper any where else, so output of 'hate' is **[1,1,0,0,0,0]** in final output string **[554, 'hate',[1,1,0,0,0,0]]**.

Please provide some solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the last value in this "helper list" ?

If not, there's some code that you may find useful.

```
import pandas as pd

n_pos = 6

lst1 = [
  [['write', 1, 1], ['bob', 1, 1], ['econom', 1, 1], ['hate', 1, 1], ['articl', 1, 1], ['mcgwier', 1, 1], ['howev', 1, 1], ['terror', 1, 1]],
  [['polit', 2, 1], ['approach', 2, 1], ['correct', 2, 1], ['hate', 2, 1], ['effect', 2, 1], ['polici', 2, 1], ['stop', 2, 1], ['wors', 2, 1]],
  [['support', 3, 1], ['organiz', 3, 1], ['directli', 3, 1], ['donat', 3, 1], ['right', 3, 1], ['indirectli', 3, 1], ['gay', 3, 1], ['issu', 3, 1]],
  [['boycott', 4, 1], ['somebodi', 4, 1], ['appar', 4, 1], ['contradict', 4, 1], ['fund', 4, 1], ['end', 4, 1], ['reconcil', 4, 1], ['scout', 4, 1]],
  [['road', 5, 1], ['saw', 5, 1], ['river', 5, 1], ['strom', 5, 1], ['research', 5, 1], ['mill', 5, 1], ['rob', 5, 1], ['ibm', 5, 1]],
  [['height', 6, 1], ['yorktown', 6, 1], ['p', 6, 1], ['box', 6, 1], ['ny', 6, 1]]
]

lst2 = [(1093, 'scout', 1), (661, 'issu', 1), (379, 'econom', 1), (1154, 'somebodi', 1), (395, 'end', 1), (57, 'appar', 1), (921, 'polici', 1), (247, 'contradict', 1), (1066, 'rob', 1), (62, 'approach', 1), (259, 'correct', 1), (1061, 'right', 1), (1377, 'write', 1), (1023, 'reconcil', 1), (1232, 'terror', 1), (1208, 'support', 1), (334, 'directli', 1), (75, 'articl', 1), (381, 'effect', 1), (624, 'indirectli', 1), (140, 'bob', 1), (502, 'fund', 1), (578, 'howev', 1), (1084, 'saw', 1), (1064, 'river', 1), (1383, 'yorktown', 1), (554, 'hate', 2), (864, 'organiz', 1), (839, 'ny', 1), (356, 'donat', 1), (560, 'height', 1), (874, 'p', 1), (1192, 'stop', 1), (1195, 'strom', 1), (145, 'boycott', 1), (1051, 'research', 1), (1372, 'wors', 1), (144, 'box', 1), (922, 'polit', 1), (1065, 'road', 1), (781, 'mill', 1), (586, 'ibm', 1), (513, 'gay', 1), (757, 'mcgwier', 1)]

# we know how many cols we expect
cols = list(range(1, n_pos+1))
# we create an index from the seconds list
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples((lst2), names=['id', 'name', 'temp'])
# we create an empty dataframe and fill it with zeroes
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols, index=index).fillna(0)
# we drop this useless last element from second list
df.index = df.index.droplevel(2)


for lst in lst1:
  for el in lst:
    name, col, val = el
    # we dont know the id so slice(None) and the second index is the name
    # thats where we set ( = val) or add ( += val) to the existing value
    df.loc[(slice(None), name), col] += val

indexes = df.index.values.tolist()
values = df.values.tolist()

# we concatenate indexes and values to your desired output
desired_output = [[*idx, vals] for idx, vals in zip(indexes, values)]
```

Which yields

```
[[1093, 'scout', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], [661, 'issu', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], [379, 'econom', [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1154, 'somebodi', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], [395, 'end', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], [57, 'appar', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], [921, 'polici', [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [247, 'contradict', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], [1066, 'rob', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], [62, 'approach', [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [259, 'correct', [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1061, 'right', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], [1377, 'write', [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1023, 'reconcil', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], [1232, 'terror', [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1208, 'support', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], [334, 'directli', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], [75, 'articl', [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [381, 'effect', [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [624, 'indirectli', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], [140, 'bob', [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [502, 'fund', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], [578, 'howev', [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1084, 'saw', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], [1064, 'river', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], [1383, 'yorktown', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [554, 'hate', [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [864, 'organiz', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], [839, 'ny', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [356, 'donat', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], [560, 'height', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [874, 'p', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [1192, 'stop', [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1195, 'strom', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], [145, 'boycott', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]], [1051, 'research', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], [1372, 'wors', [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [144, 'box', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], [922, 'polit', [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [1065, 'road', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], [781, 'mill', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], [586, 'ibm', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], [513, 'gay', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], [757, 'mcgwier', [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]]
```

Comment: I am really greateful for the effort that you have made. I am no good in 'pandas' so just let me go through all the code once by myself and also along with my logical problem, for the confermation of the correct answer. 

Once again thanks alot for this effort.

@Tom Wojcik

Comment: Sure, your question was clear and it might be difficult if you're not familiar with pandas. Once you confirm that it is what you needed please mark in as the correct answer.

Comment: Brother @Tom Wojcik I tried to check both the solution provided by you and the below. The above solution is having more time complexity than the below one. Of course for now both solution is absolutely correct. I have a very large dataset to process. For me it is not possible to come back for an error and re-do the process. Could you please give me an idea of y the below code is having less complexity.

Comment: His code is just better suited for the job. I'm fine with your decision and if time complexity matters, then his answer is the proper one. :)

Comment: I am trying to mark both as correct answer but I am not able to. Is it not possible to do that?

Comment: It's not, Mykola Zotko answer is superior to mine. Just choose his answer. It's fine, really : )

Answer (score 1):

First you can convert your unique values list `l2` into dict for look up and then using a defaultdict `d` you can process your truncated list `l1`. Finally you can convert `d` into the list of lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import chain

# l1 is your first truncated list
# l2 is your second list of unique terms

# create lookup dict
lookup = {term: {'id': id_, 'val': val} for id_, term, val in l2}

# create defaultdict with list of zeros
d = defaultdict(lambda: len(l1)*[0])

for term, pos, val in chain.from_iterable(l1):
    list_of_vals = d[(lookup[term]['id'], term)]
    list_of_vals[pos - 1] = val

# covert to list of lists
result = [(id_, term, list_) for (id_, term), list_ in d.items()]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I check the code and it is working fine. I just want to be sure that the answer is perfect thats y I am asking you one last thing. Why the above code is having more time complexity than of yours? Where you have reduced the effort?

Comment: Kindly mark up the question if you think it is a good one. I am a less privileged user right now.

Comment: @AliAbbas It’s difficult to compare, because another solution uses external library.